# Android - Failed to run command UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL DOMAIN

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I started a project with Amazon Web Services' SDK for Android. After attempting to run the code, I got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/admin/Downloads/BloomAmazon/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/admin/Downloads/BloomAmazon/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Here's my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bloom.android"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:+'
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be using the Java and not the Android SDK and hitting the Android method limit.  I suggest using the Android SDK, which is smaller, and allows you to select on a per-service basis what services to include in your app!

Checkout http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/

Comment: Thank you! This is a much better solution than what I was using!